# comment out nested triple quotes

Tags: python, comments

In python to comment-out multiple  lines we use triple quotes

```
def x():
   """This code will 
      add 1 and 1 """
   a=1+1
```

but what if I have to comment out a block of code which already contains lot of other comment out blocks (triple quote comments). For example if I want to comment out this function fully..

```
"""
def x():
   """This code will 
      add 1 and 1 """
   a=1+1
"""
```

This doesn't work. How can I comment out such blocks of code.

Comment: If you have double quotes on the inside, you can use single quotes on the outside. `''' """comment""" '''`. this works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In python to comment-out multiple lines we use triple commas

That’s just *one way* of doing it, and you’re technically using a string literal, not a comment. And, although it has become fairly established, this way of writing comments has the drawback you observed: you cannot comment out nested blocks.<sup>1</sup>

Python doesn’t have nesting multiline comments, it’s as simple as that. If you want to comment out multiple lines allowing for nested comments, the only *safe choice* is to comment out each line.

Most editors have some command that makes commenting out or in multiple lines easy.

---

<sup>1</sup> For a single level of nesting you can in fact use `'''"""nested """'''`, or the other way round. But I wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: However, the "comments" in the OP's examples are both docstrings, which might make this a bit confusing to someone coming from an environment where inline docs aren't available at runtime.

Comment: "Abusing" seems a little over-the-top, given that the technique has been endorsed by [Guido himself](https://twitter.com/#!/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248): "Python tip: You can use multi-line strings as multi-line comments. Unless used as docstrings, they generate no code! :-)"

Comment: Using an editor to do this by prepending #'s to the beginnings of lines, even with Emacs or VIM, is a bad way to do it. The triple-quote method is a de facto standard for this and the OP's question is a legitimate one.

Comment: @EMS I never doubted the question’s legitimacy. But this technique of quoting certainly isn’t a “de facto standard”. It appears to be used by some developers (Guido including, as a previous commenter noted) but that doesn’t make it a standard. What’s more, the question was about *nested multiline comments*. I challenge you to find the mistake in my answer to that question. Your assertion that it’s bad to use a text editor to comment out multiple lines is simply ridiculous.

Comment: @EMS It’s not ridiculous, I didn’t say that. What’s ridiculous is your assertion that the other method is bad. In fact, the other method is state of the art, status quo and the *one true method* supported by many text editors and IDEs. gedit in particular has a plugin to do just that. Roll your eyes all you want but don’t extrapolate your prejudice to other programmers (who are totally fine with that method of commenting).

Comment: @EMS Your whole argument isn’t cogent. In fact, there’s no argument there. You just *claim* that having to use a plugin in one particular editor makes it a bad idea. That’s not an argument. That’s a baseless assertion. And this method of quoting *is* widespread, and, I claim, definitely *more* widespread than the triple-quote method (simply due to the fact that it’s supported across languages). So yes, I stand by my assessment that your claim is ridiculous.

Comment: triple quotes is the *standard* way to do multi line comments and doctrings in python. -1 for saying it's not/ saying it' an abuse.

Comment: @Julius You did read the footnote?! But yeah, I should change the tone of my reply to reflect that  this bastardisation of the language has become an established idiom.

Answer (score 6):

What I often do in brief hack&slay situations is something like this below.  It is not really a comment, and it does not cover all cases (because you need to have a block), but maybe it is helpful:

```
if 0:  # disabled because *some convincing reason*
  def x():
   """This code will 
      add 1 and 1 """
   a=1+1
```

Or, if you cannot or don't like to introduce indenting levels between the typical ones:

```
# disabled because *some convincing reason*
if 0:  # def x():
   """This code will 
      add 1 and 1 """
   a=1+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `#` for commenting, and at the beginning of each line. This is very easy if you're using eclipse + pydev.

Simply select the block of code to comment, and press `Ctrl + \`. The same goes for uncommentng as well.

I'm sure there are such easy ways in other editors as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'm taking a Udacity python programming course building a search engine.  They use the triple quotes to enclose a webpage's source code as a string in the variable 'page' to be searched for all the links.

page = '''web page source code''' that is searched with a page.find()